# Find history of entering and exiting apps on Android

Tags: applications, logging, history

I have a Samsung Galaxy A3 2016 running Android. I would like to know whether there is a way to recover the exact history of when one entered and exited an app  during one day.

I have tried this [trick](https://thegeekpage.com/view-app-history-android-even-someone-cleared/), but it does not work.

Do you know any other solution?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anyway to get this info from Android (at least, I am not aware of it, if it exists).

You have an app alternative, [Usage Analyzer: Apps, Data & History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.kfsoft.usageanalyzer), which gives this information and much more information.

It does not give you explicitly exit time but it gives you start time and usage time, and you can add both to get exit time. Chrome usage highlighted in screenshot below

[image]

(click to enlarge )

It also gives you day/week app usage details.